# Select column data from the last 7 days and echo results?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pull amounts from the pay column of the loads table for the last 7 days and echo it to show results. i have tried several different way to do this and i am stumped.

```
<?PHP
            $startDate = date("Y-m-d");
            $endDate = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"). "-7 days");
            $lsql ="SELECT * FROM loads WHERE created_at BETWEEN '$startDate 00:00:00' AND '$endDate 23:59:59'";
                foreach ($link->query($lsql) as $ldata) { 
                    echo $ldata['pay'];
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to do:

```
SELECT * FROM loads WHERE created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;
```

directly from MySQL query. Or use [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) like:

```
SELECT * FROM loads WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

If `CURDATE()` is not working, change it to `NOW()` like:

```
SELECT * FROM loads WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```